# Processing hibernate query result

Tags: java, hibernate

I've been following this tutorial [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html)
The code from the tutorial was :

```
private void displayResult(List resultList) {
Vector<String> tableHeaders = new Vector<String>();
Vector tableData = new Vector();
tableHeaders.add("ActorId"); 
tableHeaders.add("FirstName");
tableHeaders.add("LastName");
tableHeaders.add("LastUpdated");

for(Object o : resultList) {
    Actor actor = (Actor)o;
    Vector<Object> oneRow = new Vector<Object>();
    oneRow.add(actor.getActorId());
    oneRow.add(actor.getFirstName());
    oneRow.add(actor.getLastName());
    oneRow.add(actor.getLastUpdate());
    tableData.add(oneRow);
}
resultTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(tableData, tableHeaders));
```

}

I don't understand why I can't manage to cast my Forfait forfait into (Forfait)o in my for loop.
The exception is "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to hibernate.util.Forfait"

Thanks for your help

```
public String[] getAllForfait() {
    String query = "SELECT distinct forfait.forfaitNom FROM Forfait forfait";
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query q = session.createQuery(query);
    List resultList = q.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    String[] Forfaits = {};
    int i = 0;
    for(Object o : resultList) {
        Forfait forfait = (Forfait)o;
        Forfaits[i] = forfait.getForfaitNom();
        i++;
    }
    return Forfaits;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is selecting just the name (string?) from the table:

```
String query = "SELECT distinct forfait.forfaitNom FROM Forfait forfait";
```

What you want to do it return everything, so try:

```
String query  "from Forfait"
```

instead.  This will return the full object/table instead of just a column from it.

### Update based on comment

If you need to keep the query the same, and are only looking for the name, then change your for loop to the following:

```
for(Object o : resultList) {
    Forfaits[i] = (String)o;
    i++;
}
```

You are only selecting names in your select statement, so resultList will be a list of `String`s

Comment: The request I wrote is what I needed, how can I process the result so I can store it in String[] Forfaits ?